# camera2 will crash if SurfaceView size is not one of the supported sizes

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

When using a SurfaceHolder/SurfaceView for configuring a CaptureSession, I expected that the SurfaceView can have any layout size, while I set a good preview size with the same aspect ratio for it by surfaceView.getHolder().setFixedSize(preview_width, preview_height). The result should be that the incoming preview buffer may be scaled down to the layout size.

But in camera2 - hardware level LEGACY -, configuring a CaptureSession will only work if I use a SurfaceView that has exactly the same layout size like one that is in the List returned by streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(SurfaceHolder.class). If not, the image will not be scaled down but the configuring throws an error.

```
/**
 * Prerequisites:
 * - The device must be opened.
 * - The surface view must be ready.
 */
protected void init() {

    // ...

    try {

        CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback cb = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            // ...
        };

        // The following line will result in an error*, if the viewfinder has not the right size:
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(viewfinder.getHolder().getSurface(), imageReaderSmall.getSurface()), cb, null);
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException e) {

        // ...
    }
}
```

From the log (Samsung Galaxy A3 '14, SDV v21):

```
05-12 ...: Output sizes for SurfaceHolder.class: [1440x1080, 1280x720, 960x720, 880x720, 960x540, 720x540, 800x480, 720x480, 640x480, 528x432, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144]
...
05-12 ... I/CameraManager: Using legacy camera HAL.
...
05-12 ... I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-12 ... D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096
05-12 ... D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
05-12 ....CameraActivity: Surface created
05-12 ....CameraActivity: Surface changed 4 540x405
*) 05-12 ... E/CameraDevice-0-LE: Surface with size (w=540, h=405) and format 0x4 is not valid, size not in valid set: [1440x1080, 1280x720, 960x720, 880x720, 960x540, 720x540, 800x480, 720x480, 640x480, 528x432, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144]
05-12 ... W/CameraDevice-JV-0: Stream configuration failed
05-12 ... E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
...
05-12 ....CameraActivity: Configure failed!
```

Using a Nexus 5X, SDK v23, and waiting for the `surfaceChanged()` call after `surfaceHolder.setFixedSize()`, there is no error with a preview size that is not in the list of supported output sizes, but the preview does not start. From the log:

```
05-12 08:47:10.052 ....CameraActivity: Surface created
05-12 08:47:10.053 ....CameraActivity: Surface changed 4 1455x1080
05-12 08:47:10.054 ....CameraActivity: Find preview size for 1455x1080 (1.347424:1) px
05-12 08:47:10.054 ....CameraActivity: Preview size 1600x1200 px
05-12 08:47:10.070 ....CameraActivity: Surface changed 4 1600x1200
05-12 08:47:10.110 ....CameraActivity: Session started
05-12 08:47:10.163 ....CameraActivity: Surface: Surface(name=null)/@0xec338e5
```

Result: The preview does not start, I can give the surface view a background color to demonstrate it.

How can I solve this problem and still use a SurfaceView which is more performant and backwards-compatible than using a SurfaceTexture.

Comment: The old camera API didn't care what the SurfaceView size was -- the incoming images were just scaled before display to whatever the size happened to be. What happens if you don't call `setFixedSize()`? Can you paste the actual error log into the question?

Comment: Calling `setFixedSize()` - in my case with the supported size 640x480px - will result in the same error. Rotating the device to landscape mode will work since the layouted surface view size is supported: 720x540. In the next days I will try this with a non-legacy device and will report back. If this will work then there is no problem since non-legacy devices should never use camera2 API: Many parameters are still missing that are available in the first API.

Comment: This could all be a bug with specific ROM. I would not be surprised if different devices with partial camera2 support don't have same problem. OTOH, there is an issue with camera2 API and device orientation.

Comment: The old API had an explicit Camera.Parameters.setPreviewSize method that overrode the SurfaceView's default backing buffer sizing. With the new camera2 API, setFixedSize is used instead.  In releases newer than Lollipop, the API should auto-round the size to the closest supported one, but that wasn't in the initial release.

Comment: @EddyTalvala: if `setFixedSize()` isn't called, does the Camera try to match what the SurfaceView sized itself to, or does it use a default preview size from the camera?

Comment: It tries to match the surfaceview's sizing, up to 1080p.  That doesn't fix any aspect ratio issues, note.  And as noted, this wasn't the initial camera2 behavior - we added it in Lollipop MR2, IIRC, to make things a bit simpler to use.

Comment: What is the basis of your claim that SurfaceTexture performance is worse?

Comment: @AlexCohn https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/graphics-dev/Z0yE-PWQXc4

Comment: When are you adding the Surface to the CaptureRequest targets? That also needs to happen after surfaceChanged.  Are you seeing any errors/exceptions from the setRepeatingRequest call on the 5X? Take a look at the complete logcat, not just the one filtered to your app's output, to see what the cameraservice is saying.

Comment: @EddyTalvala I create the capture session as soon as the surfaceChanged callback is called the second time (after setting the fixed size). The repeating request is started in CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback.onConfigured. There are no errors in the 5X, but the preview stays black (or transparent). Unfiltered verbose log: http://pastebin.com/u4F29Ahu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling setFixedSize, you need to wait for the surfaceChanged() callback to fire again, before creating the camera capture session.

setFixedSize queues up the necessary SurfaceView changes, but they don't take effect immediately.

Comment: So the SurfaceView will not fit its container layout?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading answers before. No, it still does not work, the preview is OK in landscape mode, but will be too small and stretched afterwards in portrait mode. The preview does not start at all on my Nexus 5X.

Comment: On the preview stretching - are you adjusting the sizing of your SurfaceView to have the right aspect ratio (setFixedSize has no impact on the layout dimensions of the SurfaceView, just its backing buffer) in portrait?  The buffers received by SurfaceView will be scaled to fill the SurfaceView's layout dimensions, so that will cause stretching if the layout dimension aspect ratio doesn't match the backing buffer aspect ratio.

Comment: Take a look at the HDR Viewfinder sample app code, which uses a SurfaceView for camera preview: http://developer.android.com/samples/HdrViewfinder/src/com.example.android.hdrviewfinder/HdrViewfinderActivity.html

Comment: Yes, I don't care about the swapped dimensions when setting fixed size, but I care about it when setting the aspect ratio of the surface view, which I swap to 3:4 (and not 4:3), and somehow the preview is rotated so that it fits reality but is stretched. I would expect a method to set the rotation, too.

Comment: This is an example of an unfiltered log running my activity in portrait mode: The surface holder does not accept the surface view having an portrait aspect ratio. The error is about the view size, not the holder size: http://pastebin.com/RFkNhFWC

Comment: @EddyTalvala Thanks, I tested this app on my 5X - and the idea is interesting. It works until the first resume (although the preview is upside down and has a significant delay) and then crashes. Problem: The test does not include portrait mode. At least I can test the included FixedAspectSurfaceView separately.

Comment: In portrait, you need the layout of the SurfaceView to be 3:4, but you need to use the same 4:3 setFixedSize.  The framework will take care of the rotation for you.  In other words, the camera device requires the same size to be given to it no matter what your app orientation is, and the rendering side of things should take care of the rotation. You just need to keep the view's aspect ratio matching the (rotated) output.

Comment: This is what I did, and it seems to be a bug either on all legacy devices or on the Samsung Galaxy A3 (2014) only.

Comment: **Important addition to the answer:** There seems to be a bug either on _devices with hardware level "legacy"_ or at least on a _Samsung Galaxy A3 (2014)_ device. I created a camera2 initialization test suite where I can switch between a SurfaceView and a TextureView. Both options work perfectly on a Nexus 5X (hardware level "full"). On my A3, only TextureView works as expected, the SurfaceView is often unpredictably skewed.